# Banach Principle in quasi metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces

What happens with the Banach contraction principle in quasi metric spaces ?   Here's the definition of a quasi metric space
[image: Quasi metric]
and here's the Banach contraction principle for metric spaces
[image: Banach fixed point theorem]
( The difference between a metric and a quasi-metric is that a quasi-metric does not possess the symmetry axiom ).

Comment: You need to define which version of completeness you are using for quasimetrics.

Comment: I just wanna know what happens with the triangle inequality in a quasi metric space.,a inequality with $d(\xi,x_n)$ where $\xi$ is the fixed point of a function. I'm sorry, my english doesn't help me too much, hope you understand.

Comment: That part is word-for-word the same as metric space case.  You don't need to use symmetry in the metric, so it works for quasimetric.

Comment: You mean there's not difference between metric space case and quasi metric space case ? I mean , if the symmetry doesn't count there, do we have the same condition to estimate the error when we solve an equation as metric spaces ? $$ d(\xi,x_n)\leq \displaystyle{{C^n}\over{1-C}}d(x_0,x_1)$$ where $0\leq C<1$ and $\xi$ the fixed point.